# How to show and hide textbox depening on mutliple select box in joomla 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I am currently developing simple custom component in joomla 3.x for sending mails to customers. In that I have one multiple select box with option to choose the customer group like members,non-members,individual.

If i choose the option Individual then i need to show the text box for enter the individual customer mail id. other two option for send mass mail.

I need the help to active show and hide function depends on the option using jquery.

[image: 1st one is For Reference]

[image: The Result should be like second image]

Comment: please show some markup at least

Comment: Thank you @axel,i have found the solution.I updated the answer also,If you have any solution better than that then advice it for me..

Comment: good job @Anitha - see my response if you'd like to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would "improve" your code in 3 aspects:

1. Stay DRY (don't repeat yourself)
2. Only use jQuery if it is necessary
3. Choose scope wisely

```js
var toggleVisbility = function( aVal, $Element ) { // #1, #2, #3
    $Element[0].style.display = aVal.indexOf('3') !== -1 ? 'initial' : 'none'; // #2
    return $Element; // #1 chainable
};

jQuery(function() { // document ready

    var $EmailId = jQuery(".emailid"),
        $FormTo  = jQuery("#jform_to") // #1
            .on('change click', function() { // #1 | on change click
                toggleVisbility( $FormTo.val(), $EmailId); // #1
            })
            .click();// #1 | trigger click on document ready

});
```

Comment: Finally someone who understands the concept of variables.

Comment: thank u @axel..for using inheritance, but i think need to pass jEmailId as parameter for fShowOrHide, without that it's not working.. I added parameter like fShowOrHide( jFormTo.val(),jEmailId) then it working perfectly.

Comment: ah jepp of course - sorry for not testing the code before posting.
you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by using `jQuery.inArray` and `.on()`-function.

In my xml file I have the following markup:

```
<field name="to" type="list" label="COM_MAILS_FORM_LBL_MAIL_TO"
       description="COM_MAILS_FORM_DESC_MAIL_TO" 
       default="0" required="true" multiple="true">
    <option value="0">All User</option>
    <option value="1">Members</option>
    <option value="2">Non-Members</option>
    <option value="3">Individual</option>
</field>
<field name="email" type="text"      
       label="COM_MAILS_FORM_LBL_EMAIL"
       description="COM_MAILS_FORM_DESC_EMAIL" />
```

In view=>edit.php the code is like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('to'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('to'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group emailid">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('email'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('email'); ?></div>
</div>
```

I have achieved to show and hide the textbox using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    emailto = $("#jform_to").val();

    if ( jQuery.inArray("3", emailto) !== -1 ) {
        jQuery(".emailid").show();
    } else {
        jQuery(".emailid").hide();
    }

    jQuery("#jform_to").on('change click',function() {
        emailto = $("#jform_to").val();
        if(jQuery.inArray("3", emailto)!==-1){
            jQuery(".emailid").show();
        } else {
            jQuery(".emailid").hide();
        }
    })

});
```

So when one chooses an individual user from multiple select box it will show the mail id textbox for individual mail address and hide the mail id text box when one removes the option from the multiple select box.

Comment: Would not suggest using a global variable, especially something as generic as that